# why is that my alternative to the method toggle in Jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, toggle, this

## Problem

I just started learning javascript. I am trying to reproduce a working piece of code in a more modular way. It helps me keep things clean, and understand it better.

I am sure that there are better efficient or concise ways to achieve what the code does so please ladies/gents don't mention it-you can save your breath on that. The point here is to learn things I do not understand yet by playing with the code.

### What does the code do

It creates an alternative method to the method [toggle that has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) 
that can then be used in the following fashion `$('#foo h2').mytoggle(plus,minus);`

### Below is the original piece of code:

```
$.fn.clicktoggle = function(a, b) {
return this.each(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(this).click(function() {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = false;
            return b.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        clicked = true;
        return a.apply(this, arguments);
    });
});
};
```

### Below is my version of the previous code:

```
function call_a_or_b (a,b) {
    var clicked = false;
    function alternate (a,b) {
        if (clicked) {
        clicked = false;
        return a.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
        clicked = true; 
        return b.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    } // end function alternate


    return $(this).each(function () {$(this).click(alternate(a,b))}); 
} //end function call_a_or_b

$.fn.clicktoggle = function(a,b) {  call_a_or_b(a,b); };
```

### Questions

1. Why the original version uses 
   `return this.each`
   instead of `return $(this).each`?

   - Note: I cannot use `this` on my version otherwise it returns an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'each'`
2. Isn't `each` a jQuery method?

   - To my understanding when using `this`, you can call DOM methods on it, but not jQuery methods. And vice versa.
3. How come my version is not working? What am I missing?

   - Note: I have no errors, so it's harder to debug.

Comment: they use `this` instead of `$(this)` because `this` has the scope of the functions of the jquery object already and so does not need to be wrapped by a jquery object

Comment: To answer your 1 and 2, have you read any [plugin tutorials](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)? The value of `this` is set depending on how a function is called, it is not automatically and always a DOM element. In the case of a plugin it will be the jQuery collection that the plugin method was called on.

Comment: Thank you guys. I did know that but I got confused because of my bad understanding of closures. It's all clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inside a plugin object `this` refers to the jQuery wrapper object on which the plugin was initiated, not the dom object as in the case of other methods
2. Since `this` is the jQuery wrapper object `.each()` is available
3. There are multiple problems in your implementation

   1. When you are calling `call_a_or_b` you are not passing the execution context to the method, so `this` inside your method refers to the `window` object
   2. As a rule of thumb, to enable chaining in jQuery you need to return the jQuery wrapper, which you are not doing
   3. There was closure and invokation related issues with the alternate method

Try

```
(function ($) {
    function call_a_or_b(a, b) {

        //for each matched element the clicked variable should be a closure one, so needed to rearrage it a bit        
        function alternate(el) {
            var clicked = true;
            $(this).click(function () {
                if (clicked) {
                    clicked = false;
                    return a.apply(this, arguments);
                } else {
                    clicked = true;
                    return b.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            })
        } // end function alternate

        return $(this).each(alternate);
    } //end function call_a_or_b

    $.fn.clicktoggle = function (a, b) {
        //call the method with the current execution context and return the value returned fromit
        return call_a_or_b.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XetMs/)

Comment: First of all, Thank you. I was impressed by the prompt reply.  You helped me focus on what I needed to in order to understand your solution. It’s very refreshing to see that there are amazing people out there.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a function to `$.fn` it gets executed in the context of jQuery , so `this` is a jQuery object. Your function gets executed most likely in the context of the window. If you change the last line to this , it should work exactly the same:

```
$.fn.clicktoggle = call_a_or_b(a,b);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but this answer is not correct in its entirety. Changing the last line does not make the code work. Remember I need to pass arguments to call_a_or_b with `mytoggle` method to begin with. Even if I didn't need to, it still wouldn't be working - I would then need to pass the execution context to the method alternate I believe. Please refer to @arun answer.